# Find the Last Cell Value of the 2nd Column Set for each 1st Column Cell in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have the following structured table in excel where 1000s of rows included.

[image]

I want to return the Last Cell Value of Column B for Each value in Column A.

For example:

1. For Cell A1 -> I want to return the Cell B5.
2. For Cell A6 -> I want to return the Cell B9.

I have tried with `VLOOKUP`, `HLOOKUP`, `INDEX` likewise so many formulas where I ended with more conflict situations. Can anyone please write down a Formula to give my requirement a life?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array formula (Press Control + Shift + Enter while entering the formula) in cell C1 and copy it down.

```
=IF(A1="","",IFERROR(INDEX($A2:$B$20,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK($A2:$A$20),0)-1,2),LOOKUP(2,1/(B2:$B$20),B2:$B$20)))
```

[image]

Comment: I see this is as a cool approach. I tried the formula. But it results the last cell value of B in each Cell. In your screenshot, the results 110, 2 and 65 all are replaced the value 65 which is the last value of Column B

Comment: Yes, all 3  cases gets 65 as result

Comment: I used ctrl + shift + enter before pasting the formula. It doesn't work paste when trying with  those keys pressed

Comment: No .. You paste the formula and then press c+s+e.. And then copy the cell and paste it down.

Comment: Pasted the formula in function bar and pressed c+s+e and it worked properly.

Comment: Yes .. that's right .. Also, you can double click on a cell, paste the formula and then press c+s+e.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't mind using column C as a helper column you could use something like that:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you won't use Array formula you can Use this solution:
like this image:
[image]

use column C as helper with this formula in first cell `=OFFSET(A1;SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A$1:$A1<>"")*(ROW($A$1:$A1))))-ROW(A1);0)`

and use this formula in column D's first cell `=IF(A1="";"";INDEX($B$1:$B$13;SUMPRODUCT(MAX((ROW($A$1:$A$13))*($C$1:$C$13=A1)))))`

and copy fill-down to all cells.

Answer (score 1):

Try this shorter, without helper column and non-array formula solution

In `C1`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(A1="","",INDEX(B1:B$9,MATCH(1,FREQUENCY(1,0+(A2:A$9<>"")),0)))
```

[image]

Comment: This is even working. But getting warning messages as well. Thank you